# Definition in satisfiability problem

Tags: logic, modal-logic

While I was reading the PhD thesis of Balder ten Cate (2005). Model theory for extended modal languages. I found a theorem that says:

**2.6.4Theorem.**
 The frame satisfiability problem for modal formulas is highly
undecidable, in fact not analytical.

My question is: What that mean highly undecidable and  not analytical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "undecidable", the author means the problem has a nonzero Turing degree - there is no algorithm that decides the problem correctly.

By "not analytical", the author means that the problem is not classifiable in the [analytical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_hierarchy). This is equivalent to saying that it is not definable by a formula of second-order arithmetic.

Appendix B of the thesis appears to have a summary of this.